# PySpark MLPC Multi Target classificaiton

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

PySpark 2.4.0

How to train a model which has multiple target columns?

Here is a sample dataset,

```
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| id|days|product|target_1|target_2|target_3|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1|   6|     55|       1|       0|       1|
|  2|   3|     52|       0|       1|       0|
|  3|   4|     53|       1|       1|       1|
|  1|   5|     53|       1|       0|       0|
|  2|   2|     53|       1|       0|       0|
|  3|   1|     54|       0|       1|       0|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

`id, days and product` are the feature columns. In order to train using PySpark ML - MLPC, i've converted the features into feature vectors.

Here is the code,

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=['id', 'days', 'product'],
    outputCol="features")
output = assembler.transform(data)
```

and i've feature column as below,

```
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
| id|days|product|target_1|target_2|target_3|      features|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
|  1|   6|     55|       1|       0|       1|[1.0,6.0,55.0]|
|  2|   3|     52|       0|       1|       0|[2.0,3.0,52.0]|
|  3|   4|     53|       1|       1|       1|[3.0,4.0,53.0]|
|  1|   5|     53|       1|       0|       0|[1.0,5.0,53.0]|
|  2|   2|     53|       1|       0|       0|[2.0,2.0,53.0]|
|  3|   1|     54|       0|       1|       0|[3.0,1.0,54.0]|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Now if i take each target columns as single label, i'll end up creating 3 models. But is there a way to convert all 3 targets(they are binary - 0 or 1) into labels.

For example if i take each target column separately then my MLPC layer will be like,

```
target_1 >> layers = [3, 5, 4, 2]
target_2 >> layers = [3, 5, 4, 2]
target_3 >> layers = [3, 5, 4, 2]
```

Since the target column contains only 0 or 1. Can i create a layer like below,

```
layers = [3, 5, 4, 3]
```

3 output for each target columns, they should give an output of 0 or 1 from every output neuron.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers,blockSize=128, seed=1234)
```

I tried to combine all targets into single label,

```
assembler_label = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=['target_1', 'target_2', 'target_3'],
    outputCol="label")
output_with_label = assembler_label.transform(output)
```

And the resulting data looks like,

```
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| id|days|product|target_1|target_2|target_3|      features|        label|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+
|  1|   6|     55|       1|       0|       1|[1.0,6.0,55.0]|[1.0,0.0,1.0]|
|  2|   3|     52|       0|       1|       0|[2.0,3.0,52.0]|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|  3|   4|     53|       1|       1|       1|[3.0,4.0,53.0]|[1.0,1.0,1.0]|
|  1|   5|     53|       1|       0|       0|[1.0,5.0,53.0]|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  2|   2|     53|       1|       0|       0|[2.0,2.0,53.0]|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  3|   1|     54|       0|       1|       0|[3.0,1.0,54.0]|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
+---+----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

When i tried to fit the data,

```
model = trainer.fit(output_with_label)
```

i got an error,

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column label must be of type numeric but was actually of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.'
```

So, is there a way to handle data like this?

Comment: Did you think of multi-label classification using OneVsRest ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It takes single target column like all other multi-label classifiers and does binary reduction for the label. It certainly can't help in this scenario when i've multiple target columns which are already binary. Or may be my understanding is wrong, is it? How can i make it accept 3 target columns with 3 neurons as output using MLPC.

Comment: was there any solution you found to this?